# Set theory, injection's existence

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Let $A^B$ be the set of all functions from $B$ to $A$, and $A \precsim B$ denotes the existence of an injection from $A$ to $B$.

I need to prove that if the $ B \precsim C$ exists, so the $B^A \precsim C^A$ exists too.

My scatchwork:
1) First of all, let's determine the following $|A|=a, |B|=b, |C|=c$.
Then, using combinatorial considerations we state that the $ |B^A|=b^a , |C^A|=c^a$. 
Also, we know that the injection from $B$ to $A$ exist, so $b \leq a$.
Using the previous inequality, we can easily state that $b^a \leq c^a$, which implies the injection's existence.

The problem is it's may be true only for a finite sets. How can we build a proof in a more common way?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's call  $\;f:B\to C\;$ an injection from $B$ to $C$.

Let's now define a function $\;g:B^A\to C^A\;$ in the following way:

$$
\forall h\in B^A, \; g(h)=f\circ h
$$

If we have that $\;g(h)=g(h')\;$ for some $h,h'$ in $B^A$, then $h=h'$, since $f$ is injective.
This means that $g$ is injective, and so $B^A \precsim C^A$